# Selecting the smallest value in one column per group

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010

I have a table that looks like the following which was created using the following code...

```
SELECT Orders.ID, Orders.CHECKIN_DT_TM, Orders.CATALOG_TYPE, 
Orders.ORDER_STATUS, Orders.ORDERED_DT_TM, Orders.COMPLETED_DT_TM, 
Min(DateDiff("n",Orders.ORDERED_DT_TM,Orders.COMPLETED_DT_TM)) AS 
Time_to_complete

FROM Orders

GROUP BY Orders.ORDER_ID, Orders.ID,
Orders.CHECKIN_DT_TM, Orders.CATALOG_TYPE, Orders.ORDERED_DT_TM, 
Orders.COMPLETED_DT_TM, HAVING (((Orders.CATALOG_TYPE)="radiology");

ID  Time_to_complete ... .....
1        5
1        7
1        8
2        23
2        6
3        7
4        16
4        14
```

I'd like to add to this code which would select the smallest Time_to_complete value per subject ID. Leaving the desired table:

```
ID  Time_to_complete ... .....
1        5
2        6
3        7
4        14
```

I'm using Access and prefer to continue using Access to finish this code but I do have the option to use SQL Server if this is not possible in Access. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if you're saying you want to filter the data, or add the new value in another column. Either way, both would be trivial in SQL Server; either by using a CTE/Subquery and `ROW_NUMBER` or using `MIN` and the `OVER` clause respectively. There are plenty of examples on SO on how to do either of these (I've seen at least 3 questions asked today for the former...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you need *correlated* subquery :

```
SELECT O.*, DateDiff("n", O.ORDERED_DT_TM, O.COMPLETED_DT_TM) AS Time_to_complete
FROM Orders O
WHERE DateDiff("n", O.ORDERED_DT_TM, O.COMPLETED_DT_TM) = (SELECT Min(DateDiff("n", O1.ORDERED_DT_TM, O1.COMPLETED_DT_TM))     
                                                           FROM Orders O1
                                                           WHERE O1.ORDER_ID = O.ORDER_ID AND . . . 
                                                          );
```

**EDIT :** If you want unique records then you can do instead :

```
SELECT O.*, DateDiff("n", O.ORDERED_DT_TM, O.COMPLETED_DT_TM) AS Time_to_complete
FROM Orders O
WHERE o.pk = (SELECT TOP (1) o1.pk  
              FROM Orders O1
              WHERE O1.ORDER_ID = O.ORDER_ID AND . . . 
              ORDER BY DateDiff("n", O.ORDERED_DT_TM, O.COMPLETED_DT_TM) ASC
             );
```

`pk` is your identity column that specifies unique entry in `Orders` table, so you can change it accordingly.

Comment: thanks! another question-so some of the ID's have the same minimum, therefor there are a number of repeating ID's in the produced table that have the same min. For example, if ID 5 have 7 records and two of which the time_to_complete variable is 3 the table output shows three rows for ID 5. What can I add to the code to show only unique values. I tried to add "distinct" after the select statement but that did not work.

Comment: @Greg. . .  In that case you can use `top (1)` inside `subquery`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:

```
DECLARE @myTable AS TABLE (ID INT, Time_to_complete INT);

INSERT INTO @myTable
VALUES (1, 5)
,      (1, 7)
,      (1, 8)
,      (2, 23)
,      (2, 6)
,      (3, 7)
,      (4, 16)
,      (4, 14);

WITH cte AS
    (SELECT *
     ,      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID  ORDER BY Time_to_complete) AS RN
       FROM @myTable)
SELECT  cte.ID
,       cte.Time_to_complete
  FROM  cte
 WHERE  RN = 1;
```

Results :

```
ID          Time_to_complete
----------- ----------------
1           5
2           6
3           7
4           14
```

It uses row numbers over groups, then selects the first row for each group.  You should be able to adjust your code to use this technique.  If in doubt wrap your entire query in a cte first then apply the technique here.

It's worth becoming familiar with this process as it gets used in a lot of places - especially around de-duping data.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This 

    DECLARE @myTable AS TABLE (ID INT, Time_to_complete INT);

    INSERT INTO @myTable
    VALUES (1, 5)
    ,      (1, 7)
    ,      (1, 8)
    ,      (2, 23)
    ,      (2, 6)
    ,      (3, 7)
    ,      (4, 16)
    ,      (4, 14);


    SELECT  O.ID, O.Time_to_complete 
    FROM @myTable O
    WHERE o.Time_to_complete  = (Select min(m.Time_to_complete) FROM @myTable m
                                                        Where o.id=m.ID
                                                              );


Result :

ID  Time_to_complete
1   5
2   6
3   7
4   14
```